# Why is pandas.join() not merging correctly along index?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, join, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes, with identical indices into a single dataframe, but i cant seem to get it working. I expect the repeated values due to the resample function. The final dataframe then seems to have sorted the indices in ascending order which is fine. But why is it now 2x as long?

Here is the code:

Original dataframe:

```
    default student balance income
0   No  No  729.526495  44361.625074
1   No  Yes 817.180407  12106.134700
2   No  No  1073.549164 31767.138947
3   No  No  529.250605  35704.493935
4   No  No  785.655883  38463.495879
... ... ... ... ...
9995    No  No  711.555020  52992.378914
9996    No  No  757.962918  19660.721768
9997    No  No  845.411989  58636.156984
9998    No  No  1569.009053 36669.112365
9999    No  Yes 200.922183  16862.952321
10000 rows × 4 columns
```

```
    X = default[['balance','income']]
    y = default['default']

    boot = resample(X,y,replace=True,n_samples = len(X),random_state=1)
    #convert to dataframe
    boot = np.array(boot)
    X = np.array(boot)[0]
    y = np.array(boot)[1]

    df = pd.DataFrame(X,index = X.index)
    dfy = pd.DataFrame(y,index=y.index)
    df = df.join(dfy)
```

X dataframe:

```
   balance        income
235    964.820253  34390.746035
5192     0.000000  29322.631394
905   1234.476479  31313.374575
7813  1598.020831  39163.361056
2895  1270.092810  16809.006452
...           ...           ...
7920   761.988491  39172.945235
1525   916.536937  20130.915258
4981  1037.573018  18769.579024
8104   912.065531  62142.061061
6990  1341.615739  26319.015588

[10000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Y dataframe

```
default
235       No
5192      No
905       No
7813     Yes
2895      No
...      ...
7920      No
1525      No
4981      No
8104      No
6990      No

[10000 rows x 1 columns]
```

Combine to give this for some reason:

```
balance income  default
0   729.526495  44361.625074    No
0   729.526495  44361.625074    No
0   729.526495  44361.625074    No
0   729.526495  44361.625074    No
1   817.180407  12106.134700    No
... ... ... ...
9998    1569.009053 36669.112365    No
9999    200.922183  16862.952321    No
9999    200.922183  16862.952321    No
9999    200.922183  16862.952321    No
9999    200.922183  16862.952321    No
20334 rows × 3 columns
```

Can someone explain where im going wrong?

Comment: there are repeated indexes, in your data frames, just create a new row for each combination, it is logical, check X.index.duplicated().any() and Y.index.duplicated().any()

Comment: if in X there are two rows with index 0 and in Y there are 3 rows with index 0 then how many rows should be created when joining? it is evident that the answer is not 3, 
6 new rows will be created, that is, one for each combination. 
So there is a reason for the increase in number of rows